# Графические эффекты на css

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть у кого мысли как сверстать эффекты как на картинке?(углы фона и блики света)

Comment: бекграунд картинками с большим z-index

Comment: @Jean-Claude, ну углы думаю никак по другому не получиться, а блики? Если поиграть с тенями? Но тогда опять же лишние блоки не несущие смысловой нагрузки.....

Comment: [Пачкой градиентов](http://a.singlediv.com/) + [habr](//habrahabr.ru/company/paysto/blog/251933/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для генерации блика можно использовать [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) или аналоги:

```css
div {
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
  background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 13%, #a3c7e2 15%, #a3c7e2 30%, #7db9e8 34%, #7db9e8 36%, #a3c7e2 40%, #a3c7e2 42%, #7db9e8 46%, #7db9e8 60%, #a3c7e2 63%, #7db9e8 65%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #ffffff 13%,#a3c7e2 15%,#a3c7e2 30%,#7db9e8 34%,#7db9e8 36%,#a3c7e2 40%,#a3c7e2 42%,#7db9e8 46%,#7db9e8 60%,#a3c7e2 63%,#7db9e8 65%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #ffffff 13%,#a3c7e2 15%,#a3c7e2 30%,#7db9e8 34%,#7db9e8 36%,#a3c7e2 40%,#a3c7e2 42%,#7db9e8 46%,#7db9e8 60%,#a3c7e2 63%,#7db9e8 65%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```